# Android SweetAlert Error : No field title_text of type I in class Lcn/pedant/SweetAlert/R$id

Tags: android, sweetalert

I'm using **SweetAlert** in my Project but in run time, I get this error message :

```
 java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No field title_text of type I in class Lcn/pedant/SweetAlert/R$id; or its superclasses (declaration of 'cn.pedant.SweetAlert.R$id' appears in /data/app/******-1/base.apk)
        at cn.pedant.SweetAlert.SweetAlertDialog.onCreate(SweetAlertDialog.java:169)
        at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:478)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:336)
        at com.soshatech.inquiry.InquiryActivity.onCreate(InquiryActivity.java:116)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6956)
```

in **proguard** file also added :

```
-keep class cn.pedant.** { *; }
-keep class cn.pedant.SweetAlert.Rotate3dAnimation {
    public <init>(...);
}
```

My Gradle file is :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "*********"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 11
        versionName "1.11"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.16'
    implementation('com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
        exclude module: ['exifinterface', 'support-annotations']
    }
    implementation('com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0') { transitive = false }
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.f0ris.sweetalert:library:1.5.6'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

when use sweetAlert in My Project above error occurred,
android studio 3.5 and latest sweetAlert
where is problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Since SweetDialog Library that you use are no longer supported since 2014, I recommended you to use [SweetAlertDialogPersian](https://github.com/sigma1326/SweetAlertDialogPersian) or [SweetAlertDialog](https://github.com/Cazaea/SweetAlertDialog) instead, and as the old one don't forget to add `-keep class com.cazaea.sweetalert.Rotate3dAnimation { public <init>(...); }` in your *Proguard Rules file*

However if you still want to use the old one try to add the following lines into your *Proguard Rules file* :

```
-keeppackagenames cn.pedant.SweetAlert.**
-keep class cn.pedant.SweetAlert.Rotate3dAnimation
-keep class cn.pedant.SweetAlert.SweetAlertDialog
```

Comment: Not Fix - I tested  SweetAlertDialog but same Error taked

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines into your  Proguard Rules

```
-keep class cn.pedant.** { *; }
-keeppackagenames cn.pedant.SweetAlert.**
```